# Why does my dropdown list reset after submit?

Tags: php, html

I have a dropdown list, which makes me show my image when i click the submit button. The problem is that my dropdown list resets the selection after pressing the button.

Another question i have is why my dropdown list shows "dots" on first two places.

```php
<form name="form1" method="post">
            <select name="case">
                <?php
            $images = scandir('images/');

            foreach($images as $image){
                echo "<option value='$image'>$image</option>";
            }
            ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
            <?php 
                if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                    echo ' <img src="images/'.$_POST["case"].'">';
                }
            ?>


        </form>
```

Comment: That's just what a submit does. If you want to save the result, you should have a mechanism in place that sets the controls to the posted values. For your second question, the list simply shows everything; if you are only interested in the images in the directory, filter the results from scandir.

Answer (score 1):

When you submit a form it reloads the page. That's why all the fields in the form are reset.

Answer (score 1):

The [`<select>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) displays the first `<option>` by default. If that isn't what you want:

> You can include a `selected` attribute on an  element to make it selected by default when the page first loads.

As about [scandir()](https://php.net/scandir), it merely reads the directory contents. Every directory in your hard disk has those two entries, either on Windows:

```
C:\Windows>dir
[…]
09/07/2019  22:11    <DIR>          .
09/07/2019  22:11    <DIR>          ..
12/04/2018  01:38    <DIR>          addins
19/05/2018  19:25    <DIR>          appcompat
[…]
```

… or Unix:

```
$ ls -al /
total 88
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root  4096 ene  1  1970 .
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root  4096 ene  1  1970 ..
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root  4096 mar 26  2017 acct
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root  4096 feb 10 18:45 bin
[…]
```

See [What are “.” and “..” in a directory?](https://superuser.com/questions/37449/what-are-and-in-a-directory) for further details.